# Add primary key in dynamodb table by using AWS Glue Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I'm trying to create an AWS Glue job where inputs are in Redshift Cluster and output table is in dynamoDB. I have mapped the columns but there's no primary key in the input table, but dynamoDB requires a primary key. For instance the input table has columns: owning_buyer, owner_code, business_name, owner_group_id, owner_group_status.

Is there a way to create random primary key value for the output table in AWS Glue job? Or do I have to edit my input table in Redshift cluster beforehand? (maybe concatting the input fields in the cluster, but I'm not sure if this is the efficient solution.)

Comment: Chances are you're trying to use DynamoDB in a way it's not intended for. You can only efficiently query by the keys later, so make sure you understand how the data is going to be accessed before you store it.

Comment: Normally the input data was kept in S3 bucket, and I don't think the primary key was needed at first when the query was written. But as the project progress, the data needs to be kept in dynamoDB, so now the primary key is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PySpark you can simply use [`pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html):

`.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id + 123)`

However, its important that your primary key in DynamoDB suits your read access patterns, if you decide to use a random unique id it may be difficult to read your items from DynamoDB. For that reason, I would suggest that you introduce a PK which is useful for your read access patterns allowing you to make efficient queries of your data and avoid using `Scan` which reads the entire dataset.

Comment: I understand your point and I agree, so I've decided to change the ETL in Cradle. Adding a random primary key may solve the dynamoDB issue, but I don't think it's that useful like you suggest. And thank you so much for your help.